# здравствуйте! возник спор: как правильно пишется данное предложение? (какие ошибки совершены?)

Tags: грамматика

Интересно, что за человек из ТТУ регулярно составляет объявления в трамваи с ошибками?

Comment: Использовать в вопросах приветствия (здравствуйте, добрый день и т.п.) не рекомендуется, но помещать их в заголовок - это уже слишком.

Comment: Для начала: сколько ошибок в вопросе, будет ли спор и надо ли их править?

Answer (score 3):

Здесь просматриваются два необычных словосочетания

1. составить (объявления) в трамвай

(составить в трамвай можно вагоны, среди которых есть ведущий)

2. трамвай с ошибками

(напр. музей ошибок, размещённый в трамвае)

Возможный вариант:

```
Интересно, что за человек в ТТУ регулярно составляет с ошибками
```

`объявления для размещения в трамваях?`

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, кто из ТТУ регулярно пишет с ошибками объявления для пассажиров трамвая?